# c# Thread sync - AutoResetEvent

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have been using an AutoResetEvent to do synchronisation between threads.

- Some threads(A-F) call autoresetevent.WaitOne(); while waiting for another thread(X) to finish its work
- whilst the thread(X) owning the autoresetevent does its work and then calls .Set();

However only one of the waiting threads(A-F) is unblocked.  - how can i get them ALL to unblock when thread(X) finishes it's work?

I guess I am using the wrong synchronisation primitive - what should i be using and how?

Code samples would be ideal

Comment: Sounds like you want to synchronize the A-F threads as well. More signals or a ManualResetEvent + Interlocked counter might work.

Comment: problem is that i dont know how many threads there will be in A-F so i cant call set the right number of times

Comment: Are you looking for [Monitor.PulseAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulseall.aspx)?

Comment: @Ani how would i use monitor.pulseAll ? would it be better than the manualresetevent mentioned below?

Comment: you should probebly consider ReaderWriterLockSlim

Comment: @Hellfrost - what are the advantages of ReaderWriterLockSlim ?

Comment: that it's designed exactly for a producer\consumer scenario, and thats what i assume you are looking for. Also you have a lot of useful stuff in the System.Collection.Concurent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) what you are looking for?

It will stay set until it is reset by some thread.

Somewhere in your code you must know when to Reset it. This might be a simple counter or collection of spawned threads.

Comment: ah ha! that sounds about right!  "When the controlling thread completes the activity, it calls Set to signal that the waiting threads can proceed. All waiting threads are released." i'll give it a go !

Comment: yep that's got it :) no idea why the manual & auto names were chosen they are not very descriptive

Comment: :) Auto automatically resets, Manual needs an explicit, or manual, action for the Event to be Set. I am glad it worked.

Comment: There's a better example/description of ManualResetEvent in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3228242/1507899

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var are = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var j = i;
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Started {0}", j);
                are.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine("Continued {0}", j); 
            }).Start();
        }

        are.Set();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

You would then get output such as this:

```
Started 0
Started 1
Started 2
Started 3
Started 4
Started 5
Started 6
Started 7
Started 8
Continued 0
Started 9
```

But if you instead use [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var j = i;
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Started {0}", j);
                mre.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine("Continued {0}", j); 
            }).Start();
        }

        mre.Set();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Then you'll get what I guess is the expected behavior:

```
Started 0
Started 1
Started 2
Started 3
Started 4
Started 5
Started 6
Started 7
Started 8
Started 9
Continued 1
Continued 8
Continued 7
Continued 4
Continued 5
Continued 6
Continued 3
Continued 0
Continued 9
Continued 2
```

Of course, as the name implies, `ManualResetEvent` needs to be *manually* reset, whereas `AutoResetEvent` *automatically* resets after the first `WaitOne` has released its thread.

Comment: Thanks for the code samples (+1) that is the problem and solution i was experiancing. Accepted Emo for being first. Still dont get the naming of these two classes!

Comment: Note that Markus Johnsson didn't call mre.Reset() (to do the manual reset). You may want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Threading.ManualResetEvent.

Threads A-F call `mre.WaitOne()` to wait on thread(X).

When thread X finishes, calling `mre.Set()` will wake threads A-F.

In thread X, reset your mre to the base state by doing `mre.Reset()`.