# How to start a loop upon button click, then stop it upon same button click again

Tags: c#, loops, button

Okay so this is my second time posting here so sorry if this question has already been answered, I couldnt find anything on it.

So basically I have a button, which I want to start a loop when its pressed, I then want the loop to keep repeating until the same button is pressed again, I've been trying to figure this out for a while and I cant seem to get this to work.

So Inside the loop, the program is changing the image inside several picture boxes, I want the program to continue changing the images in a loop until the same button is clicked

Thanks for your help :)

If you need any more information just let me know

EDIT:

```
    private void btnDance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool clicked;
        if (clicked == true)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            clicked = true;
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share a relevant snippet of what you've done so far.

Comment: This isn't showing too much

Comment: Could use a `BackgroundWorker` and that would prevent the UI from "freezing" up.

Comment: I think the real question is: Why does my application seem to freeze when I start a loop?

Comment: You're starting a loop that never terminates itself, and running that loop on the UI thread. This is keeping the UI thread from processing UI related events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think event-driven... put a timer on your form.  In the tick event do your work.  Then just have the button toggle whether the timer is active...

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Change your image here
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Toggle the timer's enabled state
        timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx). Just drop one of those from your toolbox onto your form, and start/stop it when the button is pressed. Create a handler for the [`Tick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx) event and perform the image swap within that.

Comment: How would I do this? Sorry I'm new to C#

Comment: I'd start by looking up `Timer` in MSDN.  I'm pretty sure they have some code samples there.

Comment: Ehh.. follow his instructions on how to drag and drop a Timer onto your form?

Answer (score 0):

There could be various ways:

1. Implement Pause-Resume pattern using events signals (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228211/pause-resume-thread-whith-autoresetevent) for example)
2. Keep a local `bool` variable (check it in each iteration - `break` if it is true, and update it once the button is pressed to true).
3. Or timer (as suggested)