# Stop a running loop over action in form

Tags: c#

I have a program that run in a loop.  it's this

```
private void ReadCamAuto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.serialPort1.DataReceived -= new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this.DataReceivedHandler);
    RunReadCamAuto = true;
    while (RunReadCamAuto)
    {
        serialPort1.WriteLine("2,2,2,2");
        CreatePic(4, 4);
    }
    this.serialPort1.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this.DataReceivedHandler);
}
```

but the problem is then I'm in the `While` loop I cant press any other Button in my program so it is not possible to stop. I have no idea how to stop it ?

I tried to press a button who set the `RunReadCamAuto` to false and `Console.ReadKey()`

I'm Using:

- c# Form App
- MS VS 2010

Comment: Application.ProcessMessages ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start a loop upon button click, then stop it upon same button click again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249318/how-to-start-a-loop-upon-button-click-then-stop-it-upon-same-button-click-again)

Comment: Read the serial port on a thread?

Comment: @Rob, please have a look at [the accepted answer for this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352301/how-to-use-doevents-without-being-evil).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Yes there may be issues. It may also be the correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot expect user interface to work while the main thread is busy doing some work in a loop. Use `BackgroundWorker` object to fire desired loop in it - it's automatically invoked on other thread and from your main thread you can easily send the message to stop its work.

You need to assign your method to `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork` event and then from your form just call `myBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()`. Then by calling `myBackgroundWorker.CancelAsync()` you will change its `CancellationPending` property to true, which you can be constantly checking in your loop to break execution.

Please see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).